# How to call two WCF services in my silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have two WCF services:

1. abc.svc
2. xyz.svc

I have added these to my Silverlight application successfully.

I am calling WCF services as shown below:

```
private void LoadData(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2, string str)

{

----

private int requestId = 0;

----

 Uri service = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../ALBLSalesDataService.svc");      Uri service2 = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../ALBLTargetDataService.svc");      ALBLSalesDataServiceClient oSoapClient = new ALBLSalesDataServiceClient("CustomBinding_ALBLSalesDataService", service.AbsoluteUri);      ALBLTargetDataServiceClient oSoapClient2 = new ALBLTargetDataServiceClient("CustomBinding_ALBLTargetDataService", service2.AbsoluteUri);
 Uri service = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../abc.svc");

      Uri service2 = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../xyz.svc");

      abcClient oSoapClient = new abcClient("CustomBinding_abc", service.AbsoluteUri);

     xyzClient oSoapClient2 = new xyzClient("CustomBinding_xyz", service2.AbsoluteUri);




oSoapClient.GetDataCompleted += oSoapClient_GetDataCompleted;

        oSoapClient.GetDataAsync(new DateRange(dt1,dt2), new name(str), ++requestId);



        oSoapClient2.GetDashboardTargetCompleted += (oSoapClient2_GetDashboardTargetCompleted);

        oSoapClient2.GetDashboardTargetAsync(new DateRangee(dt1,dt2), new name(str), ++requestId);




}
```

I implemented my methods, but I am not getting any data.

I am new to WCF & Silverlight. Can we call two WCF services as shown in the above code?

Comment: You define the `service` variable twice and you seem to have other spurious content on the lines. Can you edit the code so that it at least looks like it ought to work? Also can you define what you actual problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Cody,

There is no reason why you can't use more than one service at a time.  Use this code as a guide.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        string str;

        // setup of Cody's oSoapClient2 code omitted
        // ....
        // setup auth service client
        AuthenticationServiceClient client = new AuthenticationServiceClient();

        // setup oSoapClient2 and client "completed" event handlers
        oSoapClient2.GetDashboardTargetCompleted += (oSoapClient2_GetDashboardTargetCompleted);
        client.LoginCompleted += new EventHandler<LoginCompletedEventArgs>(client_LoginCompleted);

        // call each service asyncronusly
        client.LoginAsync("username", "password", "", true, null);
        oSoapClient2.GetDashboardTargetAsync(new DateRangee(dt1,dt2), new name(str), ++requestId)
    }

    void oSoapClient2_GetDashboardTargetCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       // Do something when oServiceClient2 GetDashboardTarget call completes
       if (e.Result != null)
       {
          // Do Something
       }
    }

    void client_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something when client Login service completes
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            ErrorWindow eWindow = new ErrorWindow("Login Failed", "Error: " + e.Error);
            eWindow.Show();
            return;
        }

        if (e.Result == false)
        {
            ErrorWindow eWindow = new ErrorWindow("Login Failed", "Error: Bad Username/Password combination.");
            eWindow.Show();
            return;
        }

        // Login was successful
        SuccessWindow success = new PopupWindow("Login Successful");
        success.Show();
    }
```